# О поисковой раскрутке

Tags: seo, раскрутка

Ситуация следующая: некий добрый человек прислал письмо, что он заметил на одном из сайтов недобросовестную раскрутку одного из наших сайтов(текстовый блок со ссылкой на наш сайт). В письме рассказывается какие последствия могут быть, вплоть до бана сайта поисковиками. Также вскользь предлагаются услуги по качественной раскрутке.

Может быть это письмо и осталось бы незамеченным, но мы действительно заказывали раскрутку этого сайта. Исполнители твердо утверждают, что "такими" методами они пользуются.

Со своей стороны мы поискали ссылки на наш сайт с левых сайтов (сайты непонятной тематики). Таких ссылок несколько десятков.

Собственно вопросы: кому верить? Как проверить исполнителя?
Может быть кто то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией.

Answer (score 3):

Это классика SEO-рынка: накидать в подвал сайтов, "зарабатывающих" на биржах ссылок, объявлений типа *"Продажа бетономешалок в Костроме"*.

Тут проверять особо нечего и некого: если сайт только-только появился и не содержит полезного контента, то только ссылки с внешних сайтов могут создать для поисковых машин иллюзию значимости сайта. И только биржи ссылок могут такую видимость организовать. В некоторый момент ссылок становится чересчур много, потом деньги на покупку ссылок заканчиваются и - ссылки исчезают. Видя такие всплеск и исчезновение ссылок,
поисковики действительно могут сайт сбросить вниз в серпе.

Покупка ссылок - это дело рискованное. Она имеет смысл только в том случае, если денег некуда девать, либо контент настолько интересный, что пользователи, которые придут из поисковых систем, начнут сами генерировать ссылки на ваш сайт.

Отсюда еще один вывод: гоните сеошников поганой метлой. Либо ваш проект хорош и на него начнут приходить пользователи (рано или поздно - это зависит от активности продвижения проекта: рекламы, участия в IT-тусовках и прочих мероприятий), либо не хорош - в обоих случаях SEO ни к чему.

Comment: А как на счет "добрых людей"? Они ведь тоже могут воспользоваться такой раскруткой, чтобы переманить клиента к себе.
Т.е. сами по накидают ссылок, а потом скажут: "Вон смотрите..."

Comment: Да, такое может быть, хотя если у конкурентов всё в порядке с головой - они найдут лучшее применение своим деньгам. Здесь ведь надо вложиться в покупку ссылок как минимум дважды: чтобы спровоцировать применение санкций к вашему сайту и чтобы поднять самих себя в рейтинге.